# full text search is not working on live server in laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have added full-text search in my histories table. It is working fine on local machine but on live server is giving error after taking long time.
Error is here

```
504 Gateway Time-out
```

My migration for full text search

```
     DB::statement('ALTER TABLE histories ADD FULLTEXT search(model)');
    $table->engine = 'MyISAM';
```

And this is how i am trying to use it

```
$histories->whereRaw("MATCH(model) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $strtable)
```

What could be the issue. Please guide
full query

```
$histories->whereRaw("MATCH(model) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", $strtable)->where('object_id', $po_id);
$histories->orderBy('id', 'desc');
```

Comment: Is the timeout happening during the migration to change the `histories` table, or when you execute the query?

Comment: When i am executing the query

Comment: This is the query in sql `select * from `histories` where MATCH(model) AGAINST('App\Models\Admin\Invoice' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and `object_id` = '3453' limit 20 offset 0`

Comment: Are you doing the `WHERE` clause against the `object_id` first? Can you show the full code of the `$histories` variable?

Comment: i have updated the question please have a look

Comment: object_id is also indexed

Comment: I would recommend doing the `WHERE('object_id', $po_id)` part first, ensure this completes successfully, then do the FULLTEXT part.

Comment: ok let me give a try to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232017/discussion-between-will-walsh-and-bilal-arshad).